# Netflix (Silverlight) Crashing after 30 seconds

Tags: crash, streaming, silverlight, netflix

For some reason Silverlight is crashing when I watch Netflix. It plays about 30 seconds then just stops, about 30 seconds later I get an alert saying the plugin stopped responding.

I have tried:

- Un-installing Silverlight
- Latest versions of Chrome, IE and Firefox
- The troubleshooter
- Latest version of Silverlight

FYI I am using Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

...I had written an answer to this question that I just deleted because it contained a lot of diagnostics and no answer since, at the time, I hadn't found an answer.  But I wanted to add a new answer here since (after quite a bit of trial and error) I finally found out what was the problem here - for me, anyway.

It took me quite a bit of research to find out what the problem was because the problem wasn't in a place where I thought it would be.  I thought it'd either be: an issue with Netflix itself, or one of my video card.  But it turned out to be neither.

At least for me, here's what was wrong: I connect to the internet via a DW1525 802.11n WLAN PCIe card.  It turns out that for some reason the driver this wireless card used conflicted with video on the internet so that streaming video on multiple sites online crashed frequently for me.  Windows update alone won't fix the issue, but if you have this problem and the same wireless card as I do, do a google search for that card plus drivers.  I'm now using version 8.0.0.376 from 11/23/2010 and no longer have any issues with streaming video online.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Netflix APP instead of Browser.

Also have you tried to stream any other videos with Silverlight does it also crash or only on Netflix?